# Kill process without creating core dump?

Tags: macos, signals, coredump, fuzzing

I'm fuzzing some application under MacOS 10.10.4. My fuzzer relaunches application quite often - once in ~3-4 seconds. With core dumps enabled every SIGSTOP sent to target application causes core dump creation.

How do I configure signals to which core dumps should be created (SIGSEGV, SIGBUS)? Alternatively, how to kill process so core dump wouldn't be created?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know if you can decide which signal will create core dump, you should probably send `SIGKILL` in order to kill the process, without creating a core dump.